# AngularJS / NodeJS / plain Javascript create a PDF containing prerendered HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, pdf

I know there are some posts out there, but I have not found a sufficient answer to this fundamental issue.

I want to send my customers an email with an attached PDF file in which they can find a nicely designed overview of their booking.

**Problem 1:**
That overview is can be rendered by my frontend with AngularJS very easily (including complicated logic with translations, timezones, ...) - the logic exists. Therefore, I want to let my frontend produce the HTML, that I place into the PDF file. I would have to teach my NodeJS server the whole logic too, which I want to avoid.

**Problem 2:**
How do I get my HTML code (including CSS) displayed in a PDF correctly? I have seen jsPDF and PDFmake but none seemed to work the way I wanted. They rely on html2canvas to create a canvas object from my HTML code and put it on the PDF as an image. If your "image" is bigger than 1 page, it gets even more complicated. In addition to that, the scope did not seem to be correct. The resulting image did not contain the defined div-element completely but other parts of the page instead.

I am sure many more people need something like this so I am looking for a simple, straight forward solution.

**Summary:** I want my rendered HTML + CSS from the frontend put into a PDF file.

Edit: Having a screenshot of the resulting HTML as html2canvas would do, is not optimal. Because the user cannot interact with the content (e.g. select text).

Comment: Have you checked [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) library?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am still playing with it. Let's say it can display my HTML + CSS perfectly well. How do I get the rendered stuff to the backend? I will do some tests and let you know about html-pdf.

Comment: it's already on the back-end if you're using it (html-pdf) with node.js

Comment: But then we're back to the point where I want to have the logic in the frontend. I tested yesterday night and I realized I can just send the rendered HTML + CSS to the backend (< 1KB) and then have html-pdf do it. That works I guess. Maybe I'm expecting too much here!

Comment: I ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf and it works fine. I create the html on the client side and send the resulting code to the backend. In my case it's only 300bytes or so. That's acceptible.